# Jquery timer cant reset

Tags: jquery

I am having a problem resetting my timer at the second run of the timer it always says that its not a function can you please help me

[here is the link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWXpNm?editors=1011)

```
     <div class="">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #ffcc80; margin-bottom: 5px; border-radius: 5px;">
        <strong>idle: </strong><span id = "ctr_idle">0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #ff9980; margin-bottom: 5px; border-radius: 5px;">
        <strong>talk_time: </strong><span id = "ctr_talk">0</span>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #66c2ff; margin-bottom: 5px; border-radius: 5px;">
        <strong>ON HOLD: </strong><span id = "ctr_hold">0</span>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #99e699; margin-bottom: 5px; border-radius: 5px;">
        <strong>AFTERTALK: </strong><span id = "ctr_aftertalk">0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #ffff99; margin-bottom: 5px; border-radius: 5px;">
        <strong>TOTAL: </strong><span id = "ctr_total">0</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that there was duplicate function **count_aftertalk** so i had commented out and change variable function declaration type. You can compare this with old code then you will get it.

USE THIS CODE I HOPE IT WILL WORK FINE IT WILL NOT SHOW **its not a function**

```
var timer_idle;
var timer_talk;
var timer_hold;
var timer_aftertalk;

var count_idle;
var count_talk;
var count_hold;
var count_aftertalk;

var zero = parseInt("0");

count_idle = function (sec) {
    clearInterval(timer_idle);
    clearInterval(timer_talk);

    timer_idle = setInterval(function() { 
        $('#ctr_idle').text(sec++);
    }, 1000);
}

count_talk = function (sec) {
    clearInterval(timer_idle);
    timer_talk = setInterval(function() { 
        $('#ctr_talk').text(sec++);
    }, 1000);
}

count_hold = function (sec) {
    clearInterval(timer_talk);
    timer_hold = setInterval(function() { 
        $('#ctr_hold').text(sec++);
    }, 1000);
}

count_aftertalk = function (sec) {
    clearInterval(timer_talk);
    timer_aftertalk = setInterval(function() { 
        $('#ctr_aftertalk').text(sec++);
    }, 1000);
}

/*function count_aftertalk(sec) {
    clearInterval(timer_talk);
    timer_aftertalk = setInterval(function() { 
        $('#ctr_aftertalk').text(sec++);
    }, 1000);
}*/

count_idle(zero);

$("#reset").click(function() {
    count_idle(zero);
  $('#ctr_talk').text(0);
  $('#ctr_hold').text(0);
  $('#ctr_aftertalk').text(0);
  $('#ctr_total').text(0);

  console.log(count_talk);
});

$("#start").click(function() {
    clearInterval(timer_idle);
    count_talk(zero);
});

$("#hold").click(function() {
    clearInterval(timer_talk);
    num = $('#ctr_hold').text();
    count_hold(num);
});

$("#unhold").click(function() {
    clearInterval(timer_hold);
    num = $('#ctr_talk').text();
    count_talk(num);
});

$("#finish").click(function() {
    clearInterval(timer_talk);
    num = $('#ctr_aftertalk').text();
    count_aftertalk(num);
});

$("#total").click(function() {

    clearInterval(timer_aftertalk);

    talk = parseInt($('#ctr_talk').text());
    hold = parseInt($('#ctr_hold').text());
    aftertalk = parseInt($('#ctr_aftertalk').text());
    sum = talk + hold + aftertalk;

    count_total = $('#ctr_total').text(sum);

});
```